# How to change TinyMCE external_image_list_url from code

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, tinymce, imagelist

when the user is about to add an image to an article i used the image list to enable him add images in a separate section and add them to article from tinyMCE but what will happen if we have a massive amount of images the user will find a long list!! it will not be easy at all?
so i wish to find a way to lmake each article has its own images list **images_list.php?article_id=333..** .

an accordion is the container of all articles titles in a section
when click edit or add ajax with tinymce do the work
but how to change the external_image_list_url property of each article?????

Comment: when you initialize tinymce does the user treat only one article or several?

Comment: several articles [all articles of a section] but only two tinyMCE instance

Comment: the two instances of tinyMCE are used each edit or addition for one article [English and Arabic]

Comment: i am sorry, i still do not get your use-case scenario (which is essantial to answer your question) if necessary post an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when generating the javascript List with a php-file, like this example from moxiecode, you should be able to get your images depending on the article.

Have fun !

Example of a PHP-generated image list file

```
<?php // this must be the very first line in your PHP file!

// You can't simply echo everything right away because we need to set some headers first!
$output = ''; // Here we buffer the JavaScript code we want to send to the browser.
$delimiter = "n"; // for eye candy... code gets new lines

$output .= 'var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(';

$directory = "../../img"; // Use your correct (relative!) path here

// Since TinyMCE3.x you need absolute image paths in the list...
$abspath = preg_replace('~^/?(.*)/[^/]+$~', '/$1', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if (is_dir($directory)) {
    $direc = opendir($directory);

    while ($file = readdir($direc)) {
        if (!preg_match('~^.~', $file)) { // no hidden files / directories here...
             if (is_file("$directory/$file") && getimagesize("$directory/$file") != FALSE) {
                // We got ourselves a file! Make an array entry:
                $output .= $delimiter
                    . '["'
                    . utf8_encode($file)
                    . '", "'
                    . utf8_encode("$abspath/$directory/$file")
                    . '"],';
            }
        }
    }

    $output = substr($output, 0, -1); // remove last comma from array item list (breaks some browsers)
    $output .= $delimiter;

    closedir($direc);
}

// Finish code: end of array definition. Now we have the JavaScript code ready!
$output .= ');';

// Make output a real JavaScript file!
header('Content-type: text/javascript'); // browser will now recognize the file as a valid JS file

// prevent browser from caching
header('pragma: no-cache');
header('expires: 0'); // i.e. contents have already expired

// Now we can send data to the browser because all headers have been set!
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: i'm using this code provided by moxiecode and i can get different image lists but i have alist of articles and only one tinymce instance when the user select an article and click edit the content of selected article is requested from server with ajax and is set to the tinymce and show it. the problem is that i instantiate tinymce with the list url at the startup but i need to make it variable, i need to change it with each article editing before making editor visible.